# How to select Date in the CalendarView

Tags: swift3, jtapplecalendar

hi newBiew in JTAppleCalendar.
I have following this link for creating a Calendar base on JTAppleCalendar.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQNotydm58s&index=6&list=PLpqJf39XekqyUG7dxcqGO0JNprryysv9Q

I could not figure how to get a date after user press the date on the Calendar.

Here the code:
in the  didSelectDate.  The date return is always one day behind??

This is what I wanted to achieve. When user tap on the date on the calendar, I want to get the date and use this date to request data from the server,

```
extension MyCalendar: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource, JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate {

    func configureCalendar( _ calendar:JTAppleCalendarView) ->ConfigurationParameters{

        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
        formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
        formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

        let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 01")!
        let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2027 12 31")!        

        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate : startDate, endDate: endDate)          
        return parameters

    }


  func calendar( _ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell{


        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text

        configureCell(cell:cell, cellState: cellState)

        return cell

    }


    //------------ selected item

    func calendar( _ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell:JTAppleCell?, cellState:CellState){

        // cell is option
        configureCell(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)

       //prolem:
        let strdate = cellState.date

    }


    func calendar( _ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didDeselectDate date: Date, cell:JTAppleCell?, cellState:CellState){

        // cell is option
        configureCell(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)

    }

   func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didScrollToDateSegmentWith visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo) {

       setupCalendarView(dateSegment: visibleDates)

    }

}
```

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: Just a question, why are you using cellState.date and not date that should be your selected date?

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro, would appreciate  to show me how. I did try let d: Date = date , but d has nothing.

Comment: I have found this issue @MilkBottle check it: [Wrong date](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/252)

Comment: You say that the problem is `let strdate = cellState.date` how did you know it was a problem, did you print it to the console?

Comment: I m newbie. I set a breakpoint at  let strdate = cellState.date, I see it is one day behind, so I use let newDate = Date(timeInterval:86400,since strdate) this will provide correct date. Now I use let strDate = formatter.string(from:date) as per Francesco. it provide correct date now. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: I have sent you my app. There are a few features I m not familiar. Hope you can show me how to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle ok the answer is found here -> https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/252   Never look at xcode console to see the correct date. The print command and also the XCode display for dates comes with its **own** formatting with might be different than your time zone. The date you see visually only "looks" incorrect because of that wrong formatting. To display dates correctly in iOS, always use a DateForamatter. The link i posted above explains it for you. This question exists in any iOS calendar library you use.

Comment: @iOS calendar, Thank you so much. How to mark this as solved.

Comment: i converted my comment to an answer. You can accept it as correct :) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is found [in this github issue](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/252). Never look at xcode console to see the correct date. The print command and also the XCode display for dates comes with its own formatting with might be different than your time zone. The date you see visually only "looks" incorrect because of that wrong formatting. To display dates correctly in iOS, always use a DateForamatter. The link i posted above explains it for you. This question exists in any iOS calendar library you use.